# Enable SSL on Ruby on Rails app with Nginx and Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

Here is my Nginx conf file:

```
upstream app {
  server unix:/home/deploy/example_app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  # ssl on;
  server_name localhost example.com www.example.com;

  root /home/deploy/example_app/current/public;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location /.well-known { allow all; }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

The path to certificates are correct but when I access https://example.com it stay loading forever.

Is there any problem with my SSL setup?

Comment: Why is ssl on commented out?

Comment: When I uncomment I get this error: 400 Bad Request. The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port.

Comment: As I'm reading in Nginx docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html there is no need for this. @j-dexx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [SSL checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) to check whether the SSL is a problem or not.

It will verify your server certificate and tell you where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I ensure that the domain name resolved to the IP correctly. The port 443 is allowed on Firewall on my Ubuntu and also ensure that the certificate from Let's Encrypt is installed on my server correctly.

I use AWS EC2 and it took me hours to find that I forgot to add **HTTPS** into the **Inbound rules** in the EC2 instance **Security Group**.

I can access https://mydomain again just after added the rule on the AWS EC2.